# Joining two strings together then converting to an integer. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have to write a program so that a user can increase $100 by a percentage they input.I need to do 100 * 1.n, but I keep getting an error as I am converting a string into an integer, please help;

```
percent = input("Enter the % you want to increase by: ")
n = "1." + percent
k = int(n)
print(k)
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\T Pad\Downloads\dlee.py", line 3, in <module>               
 k = int(n)
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.50'
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: You get a string with `input()`, don't have to explicitly convert it.

Comment: I think you want to convert it to a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert it to `int`, you need `float`.

```
percent = '2837' #input("Enter the % you want to increase by: ")
n = "1." + percent
k = float(n)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to convert a string containing floating number to an int, that raises a `ValueError` so if you want a floating point number,

```
percent = input("Enter the % you want to increase by: ")
n = "1." + percent
k = float(n)
print(k)
```